# How to use ScrollToItem(at:) when using a custom collectionView layout to alter cell sizes

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a custom layout for a collectionView. This custom layout increases the width of the center cell. Here is the custom layout class that does this. Look at the shiftedAttributes function to see how its done

```
class CustomCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {

    private var cache = [IndexPath: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    private var contentWidth = CGFloat()
    private var visibleLayoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    private var oldBounds = CGRect.zero
    private var cellWidth: CGFloat = 5
    private var collectionViewStartY: CGFloat {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else {
            return 0
        }
        return collectionView.bounds.minY
    }
    private var collectionViewHeight: CGFloat {
        return collectionView!.frame.height
    }
    override public var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: collectionViewHeight)
    }

    override public func prepare() {
        print("calling prepare")
        guard let collectionView = collectionView,
            cache.isEmpty else {
                return
        }

        updateInsets()
        collectionView.decelerationRate = .fast
        cache.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
        cache = [IndexPath: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
        oldBounds = collectionView.bounds
        var xOffset: CGFloat = 0
        var cellWidth: CGFloat = 5

        for item in 0 ..< collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {
            let cellIndexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)
            let cellattributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: cellIndexPath)
            cellattributes.frame = CGRect(x: xOffset, y: 0, width: cellWidth, height: collectionViewHeight)
            xOffset = xOffset + cellWidth
            contentWidth = max(contentWidth,xOffset)
            cache[cellIndexPath] = cellattributes
        }
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        visibleLayoutAttributes.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)

        for (_, attributes) in cache {
            visibleLayoutAttributes.append(self.shiftedAttributes(from: attributes))
        }
        return visibleLayoutAttributes
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        guard let attributes = cache[indexPath] else { fatalError("No attributes cached") }
        return shiftedAttributes(from: attributes)
    }
    override public func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        if oldBounds.size != newBounds.size {
            cache.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)
        }
        return true
    }

    override func invalidateLayout(with context: UICollectionViewLayoutInvalidationContext) {
        if context.invalidateDataSourceCounts { cache.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true) }
        super.invalidateLayout(with: context)
    }
}
extension CustomCollectionViewLayout {

    func updateInsets() {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }
        collectionView.contentInset.left = (collectionView.bounds.size.width - cellWidth) / 2
        collectionView.contentInset.right = (collectionView.bounds.size.width - cellWidth) / 2
    }
    override func targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset proposedContentOffset: CGPoint, withScrollingVelocity velocity: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return super.targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset: proposedContentOffset) }
        let midX: CGFloat = collectionView.bounds.size.width / 2
        guard let closestAttribute = findClosestAttributes(toXPosition: proposedContentOffset.x + midX) else { return super.targetContentOffset(forProposedContentOffset: proposedContentOffset) }
        return CGPoint(x: closestAttribute.center.x - midX, y: proposedContentOffset.y)
    }

    private func findClosestAttributes(toXPosition xPosition: CGFloat) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return nil }
        let searchRect = CGRect(
            x: xPosition - collectionView.bounds.width, y: collectionView.bounds.minY,
            width: collectionView.bounds.width * 2, height: collectionView.bounds.height
        )
        let closestAttributes = layoutAttributesForElements(in: searchRect)?.min(by: { abs($0.center.x - xPosition) < abs($1.center.x - xPosition) })
        return closestAttributes
    }
    private var continuousFocusedIndex: CGFloat {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return 0 }
        let offset = collectionView.bounds.width / 2 + collectionView.contentOffset.x - cellWidth / 2
        return offset / cellWidth
    }
    private func shiftedAttributes(from attributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
        guard let attributes = attributes.copy() as? UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes else { fatalError("Couldn't copy attributes") }
        let roundedFocusedIndex = round(continuousFocusedIndex)
        let focusedItemWidth = CGFloat(20)
        if attributes.indexPath.item == Int(roundedFocusedIndex){
            attributes.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 10, y: 1)
        } else {
            let translationDirection: CGFloat = attributes.indexPath.item < Int(roundedFocusedIndex) ? -1 : 1
            attributes.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: translationDirection * 20, y: 0)
        }
        return attributes
    }
}
```

Here is the View Controller which contains the collectionView that uses this layout:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = customCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "singleCell", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.random()
        return cell
    }
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var customCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        customCollectionView.delegate = self
        customCollectionView.dataSource = self
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.dataSource = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    @IBAction func goTo(_ sender: Any) {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: picker.selectedRow(inComponent: 0), section: 0)
        customCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }

}

extension ViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return String(row)
    }       
}
```

Note the pickerView where you can pick an index that is used in the goTo button to scrollTo the item at that index. Here it is in action:

[image]

See how even though I am staying on the same index, it keeps scrolling around, and doesn't really scroll to that index anyway. When I don't shift the attributes (with shiftedAttributes) and just return them normally in the custom layout, the scrollTo works fine.

So it seems something about the placement of each cell is used when doing scrollToItem(at:) which is getting confused by the shifted attributes? How do I scroll to a particular index when the sizes of the cells are subject to change?

EDIT: [here](https://github.com/AlexMarshall12/customTimeline) is the entire project code if you wanna try it yourself:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears that `scrollToItem()` is using a fixed layout size.

I think you will have to calculate the offset manually and use `setContentOffset()`

```
//To do: Calculate widths of cells up to the cell you want to scroll to
var calculatedOffset: CGFloat 

//Then scroll to the offset calculated
customCollectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: calculatedOffset, y: 0.0), animated: true)
```

Comment: but what if you are scrolling to something really far away in the collectionView that hasn't loaded yet?

Comment: Only the first few cells are large, then all the rest of them are a standard size, right? If so, it's just a matter of determining the special cell sizes (which your custom layout is doing) and adding them to the standard width multiplied by the row number you want to scroll to.